# Admob Interstitial Ads showing in middle of the game

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm trying to put interstitial ads when the game over.but
interstitial ads always show in the middle of the game. I think it'll be annoying for users

here's the code to show admob interstitial ads when the game was over

the methods to initialize the interstitial ads

this is main.java file

```
// AdMob
AdView adMob_smart;
InterstitialAd adMob_interstitial;
final boolean show_admob_smart = true; // show AdMob Smart banner
final boolean show_admob_interstitial = true; // show AdMob Interstitial

  // add_admob_smart
void add_admob_smart() {
    if (show_admob_smart
            && ((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo() != null) {
        adMob_smart = new AdView(this);
        adMob_smart.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.adMob_smart));
        adMob_smart.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.admob)).addView(adMob_smart);
        com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        // builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("4d0555dfcad9b000");
        adMob_smart.loadAd(builder.build());
    }
}

// add_admob_interstitial
void add_admob_interstitial() {
    if (show_admob_interstitial
            && ((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo() != null) {
        adMob_interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        adMob_interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.adMob_interstitial));
        com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        // builder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("4d0555dfcad9b000");
        adMob_interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                adMob_interstitial.show();
            }
        });
        adMob_interstitial.loadAd(builder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (gameOver){
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use one flag e.g.gameOver.

```
if (gameOver){
adMob_interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            adMob_interstitial.show();
        }
 });
}
```